# NoMethodError: undefined method `cattr_accessor' for OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, virtualbox

I am able to bundle but rake command giving me following error

$ rake db:drop

rake aborted!

NoMethodError: undefined method `cattr_accessor' for OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover:Class

C:/Users/*****/Documents/*****/New folder/pam_client/lib/pam_client.rb:2:in `require'
C:/Users/*****/Documents/*****/New folder/pam_client/lib/pam_client.rb:2:in`'
C:/Users/*****/Documents/*****/New folder/pam_client/Rakefile:3:in `require'
C:/Users/*****/Documents/*****/New folder/pam_client/Rakefile:3:in`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

i have tried all the solutions but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade to rails 4.1 to get cattr_accessor to work. Perhaps one of your gems is trying to run this method, but your rails install is too old to support it?